# keep ontouch event when view is removed and add

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have a view in a linearlayout. When the view is longpressed the view will be removed from this linearlayout and placed, on the same position of the screen, to a relative layout. On this way a can move the view over the screen with my finger.

it almost works:
i got the longpress event working (remove the view and place the view to the relativelayout). after that i add an ontoucheventlistener so my view stays with my finger, **but only for a second**. the last time the touchevent is fired i got "MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL". When i remove my finger and place my finger again to the view i can go feature with my movement, then it will keep until i remove my finger.

<strike>I think that my problem is that the view it removed for a short moment, at that time i get a "MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL", however, there are still some unhandled events, they will be fired first. Thats why i got for about 1 second still ontouchevents. (this is just a thought).</strike>

someone a idee how i can keep the ontouchevent, or let the ontouchevent fired without replacing my finger?

**Edited**

My thought is not correct. When i do a longpress the view stays with my finger, however i lost the view as soon as i move about 50 to 100 pixels to any direction.

**Edited 2**

the longpress code of the view inside the linearlayout

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        _linearLayout.removeView(v);
        moveView(v);
        return true;
    }
});
```

moveView will be called by the longpress

```
private void moveView(View v) {
        _relativeLayout.addView(v);
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y = (int) event.getRawY();                          
                    v.layout(x, y, x + v.getWidth(), y + v.getHeight());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    _relativeLayout.removeView(v);
                    v = null;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    //it comes here when i move my finger more then 100 pixels
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

of corse, this is the relevant part of the code and not the original code

Comment: Sounds like a better design would be to not switch layouts but try make them both work in RelativeLayout

Comment: true, can't say directly if this is posible, because of the sideway and updownscrolling and other complex interactions on the screen.. but maybe you are right.

Comment: a this is not posible. The view is inside a scrollcontainer. but as soon as i can move the view, the view must also go out of this scrollcontainer to other parts of the screen.

Comment: So you replace the whole view or do you have a LinearLayout which is replaced completely by a RelativeLayout

Comment: Could you paste the listener code?

Comment: the linearlayout is (in a scrollview) on the relative layout. I remove the view from the linearlayout and place the same view to the relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Experience - Android Drag and Drop List](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html) post. There is also [a source code](https://sites.google.com/site/ericbharlow/sample-code/DragNDrop.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) that does something very similar to what are you trying to get. Eric, the author of that post, uses a separate temporary `ImageView` to hold a dragged view image, taken with `getDrawingCache()`. He also hides the original list item by `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

In the DragNDrop project (link above) you can replace `drag(0,y)` calls by `drag(x,y)` in DragNDrop.java to see a dragging in all directions.

Comment: i see, this eric has on the container a touchevent and with the x and y he finds the view that should be moved. maybe it can help.. i will check tommorow

Comment: i have it working. i have a class that extends the relativelayout and override the onintercepttouchevent. in that function it will check if the linearlayout has a view on that position (x and y). If not, lose interception, otherwise, keep and check if x and y in the next 50 cycles will not moved to far. 50 cycles later, take ownership of touchevent and remove view from linearlayout and place it to the relative layout.. keep redrawing the view while relativelayout is touched. So THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing some possibilities in because I can't see the code but `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` could be being called as the parent layout is switched and the view is getting redrawn.

You could try overriding the `onTouchEvent` and at the point the ACTION_CANCEL event is sent try get hold of an equivalent view in the new layout and operate on that but I still think the better idea is to redesign so it all takes place in the same layout.

Comment: this is what i want, but can't get it working... however.. the idee of praetorian droid may help me.